# What error currently exists in the ssl.cnf file or code that is leading to the following output in zsh?

Tags: ssl, alexa-skills-kit

Recently I was working on a project that utilized the Alexa AVS Sample App (the one written in java, and currently in maintenance mode: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/wiki/Mac#4---generating-self-signed-certificates) and when I was attempting to follow the given instruction:

> 4. Edit the ssl.cnf configuration file with your favorite text editor. Replace any placeholder values that start with YOUR_.
>      Note: countryName must be two characters (e.g. US). If it is not two characters, certificate creation will fail. Additionally, if you will be accessing your device from any IP or DNS entry besides localhost (127.0.0.1 or 10.0.2.2), you must add the additional IP or or DNS entries to [alt_names]. One situation where you will need to add entries to [alt_names] is if you are going to authenticate using an Android or iOS companion app from a device instead of from the Android or iOS emulators on the same machine as the Node.js server and sample app.

I edited the file as said, and not sure if I did do it correctly, but her goes:

```
[req]
distinguished_name      = req_distinguished_name
prompt                  = no

[v3_req]
subjectAltName          = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1                   = localhost
IP.1                    = 127.0.0.1
IP.2                    = 10.0.2.2

[req_distinguished_name]
commonName              = $ENV::COMMON_NAME                 # CN= Random
countryName             = YOUR_COUNTRY_NAME                 # C= US
stateOrProvinceName     = YOUR_STATE_OR_PROVINCE            # ST= CA
localityName            = YOUR_CITY                         # L= San Francisco
organizationName        = YOUR_ORGANIZATION                 # O= VEor
organizationalUnitName  = YOUR_ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT          # OU= VE
```

I also did previously replace the YOUR_ORGANIZATION and etc. with the country codes and etc. themselves, like the following:

```
[req]
distinguished_name      = req_distinguished_name
prompt                  = no

[v3_req]
subjectAltName          = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1                   = localhost
IP.1                    = 127.0.0.1
IP.2                    = 10.0.2.2

[req_distinguished_name]
commonName              = $ENV::COMMON_NAME                 # CN= Random
countryName             = US                 # C= 
stateOrProvinceName     = CA            # ST= 
localityName            = San Francisco                         # L=
organizationName        = VEor                 # O= 
organizationalUnitName  = VE
```

### Yet, I still get this output:

```
❯ ./generate.sh
Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus
...........................++
.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
error on line 14 of ssl.cnf
140736175395720:error:0E065068:configuration file routines:STR_COPY:variable has no value:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22/libressl/crypto/conf/conf_def.c:573:line 14
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
...........+++
........+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
error on line 14 of ssl.cnf
140736175395720:error:0E065068:configuration file routines:STR_COPY:variable has no value:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22/libressl/crypto/conf/conf_def.c:573:line 14
certs/client/client.csr: No such file or directory
Error opening input file certs/client/client.crt
certs/client/client.crt: No such file or directory
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
......................................................................................................................................+++
....+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
error on line 14 of ssl.cnf
140736175395720:error:0E065068:configuration file routines:STR_COPY:variable has no value:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22/libressl/crypto/conf/conf_def.c:573:line 14
certs/server/node.csr: No such file or directory
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
....+++
...................................+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
error on line 14 of ssl.cnf
140736175395720:error:0E065068:configuration file routines:STR_COPY:variable has no value:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22/libressl/crypto/conf/conf_def.c:573:line 14
error on line 14 of config file 'ssl.cnf'
Error opening input file certs/server/jetty.crt
certs/server/jetty.crt: No such file or directory
cp: certs/ca/ca.crt: No such file or directory
Error opening Certificate certs/ca/ca.crt
140736175395720:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22/libressl/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:255:fopen('certs/ca/ca.crt', 'r')
140736175395720:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22/libressl/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:257:
unable to load certificate
cp: certs/ca/ca.der: No such file or directory
```

What should I do differently to ensure it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please modify ur openssl directory in generate.sh

->/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl

https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/issues/1004